# Pass array to another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to change ownership of files in Google Drive, where my service account isn't owner of the file.

```
 function getDriveFiles(folder, path) {
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B23heXhtbThYaWdxzMc");
   var path = "";
    var files = [];
    var fileIt = folder.getFiles();
    while ( fileIt.hasNext() ) {
        var f = fileIt.next();
      if (f.getOwner().getEmail() != "service@domain.com")
        files.push({owner: f.getOwner().getEmail(), id: f.getId()});
    }
    return files;
}
```

So my array looks like this:

```
  var files = [
     {owner=jens@domain.com, id=CjOqUeno3Yjd4VEFrYzg},
     {owner=jens@domain.com, id=CjOqUYWxWaVpTQ2tKc3c},
     {owner=jens@domain.com, id=CjOqUNTltdHo2NllkcWs},
     {owner=jens@domain.com, id=CjOqUVTRRMnU2Y0ZJYms},
     {owner=jack@domain.com, id=CjOqUXzBmeE1CT0VLNkE}, 
     {owner=aurora@domain.com, id=CjfKj4ur7YcttORkXTn8D2rvGE},
     {owner=aurora@domain.com, id=CjOqUY3RFUFlScDBlclk}
    ]
```

Next function that i need to pass this array to is batchPermissionChange which will batch change the ownership to my service account. However i would like it to run batchPermissionChange per user. So if e.g jens@domain.com have 4 files, i don't want the batchPermissionChange function to be triggered 4 times, i would like it to trigger it one time with jens@domain.com, and include his four fileID's.

```
function batchPermissionChange(ownerEmail, filesArray){
Do batch job Google... https://www.googleapis.com/batch
}
```

**Question**

How do i run the function batchPermissionChange(ownerEmail, filesArray) with for e.g jens@domain.com with his 4 fileId's? I could loop through the array, like, 'for each item in array run batchPermissionChange', but that will trigger the batch-function 4 times for the user jens@domain.com.

Comment: so what is the issue? What are you having trouble with? You don't actually ask a question here.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the list of files, instead of pushing all the files into a single array, you can create a map of arrays, with the keys in the map being the owners, and the arrays being the list of files for that owner.

```
function getDriveFiles(folder, path) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B23heXhtbThYaWdxzMc");
  var path = "";
  var files = {};
  var fileIt = folder.getFiles();
  while (fileIt.hasNext()) {
    var f = fileIt.next();
    var owner = f.getOwner().getEmail();
    var id = f.getId();

    if (owner != "service@domain.com") {
      // if the owner doesn't exist yet, add an empty array
      if (!files[owner]) {
        files[owner] = [];
      }

      // push the file to the owner's array
      files[owner].push(id);
    }
  }
  return files;
}
```

The `files` object will end up looking something like this:

```
{
  'jens@domain.com': ['CjOqUeno3Yjd4VEFrYzg', 'CjOqUYWxWaVpTQ2tKc3c', 'CjOqUNTltdHo2NllkcWs', 'CjOqUVTRRMnU2Y0ZJYms'],
  'jack@domain.com': ['CjOqUXzBmeE1CT0VLNkE'],
  'aurora@domain.com': ['CjfKj4ur7YcttORkXTn8D2rvGE', 'CjOqUY3RFUFlScDBlclk']
}
```

Now, in the area of your code where you want to call `batchPermissionChange`, do it like this:

```
for(var ownerEmail in files) {
  if(files.hasOwnProperty(ownerEmail)) {
    // NOTE: I'm not sure what the first parameter should be for this, but 
    // this shows how to send the array of files for just one user at a 
    // time, so change the first parameter if I got it wrong.
    batchPermissionChange(ownerEmail, files[ownerEmail]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly something like this is what i'm looking for. I tried your suggestion, but the array is looking the same it did before. Should the array look the same or should i be able to see any visual changes?

Comment: It should be very different. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I see, maybe the last part where i send the array of files is wrong, I'm not quite sure with the "var owner;" and "ownerEmail".

Comment: oops, I fixed the var owner part. I had made a mistake there. It should make sense now.

Comment: Ah stupid me! I thought that the instructions you provided me where super clear, by the book this should work. I was targeting wrong function when testing. Yes now the array look's different (as it should). Will try to pass it through to the batch function now. Brb :)

Comment: Id did just what I asked for, however i also have a subfolder scan in the same function, that now dosen't work, but i'll start a new thread..